# Why in this code, the static int doesn't change or give a compilation error?

Tags: c++, static, header, int, output

I have a code here. It was a puzzle to solve. However I couldn't understand the part about the `header_var` which is a ***static int***. Why is it possible to change the value of `header_var` from **q1_main.cpp** and that it doesn't change its value in **q1_helper.cpp**.Also why don't I receive any warning or compilation error?

Below are the codes:

**q1_main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "q1_header.h"
using namespace std;
void func_1(int param_1);
void func_2(int& param_2);
void func_3(int* param_3);
void func_4();
int global_var = -1;
int main() {
    int local_var_1 = -1;
    int local_var_2 = -1;
    int *local_var_3 = new int;
    *local_var_3 = -1;
    //The first line of the output
    func_1(local_var_1);
    func_2(local_var_2);
    func_3(local_var_3);
    cout << local_var_1 << " " <<
        local_var_2 << " " <<
        *local_var_3 << endl;
    //The second line of the output
    func_1(global_var);
    cout << global_var << endl;
    //The third line of the output
    header_var = 5;
    func_4();
    cout << global_var << " " <<
        header_var << endl;
    //The fourth line of the output
    loop(i, 2) {
        static int static_var = 0;
        cout << static_var++ << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**q1_helper.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "q1_header.h"
extern int global_var;
void func_1(int param_1) {
    param_1 = 100 / ADD(2,3);
}
void func_2(int& param_2) {
    param_2 = 100 / MUL(50, 2);
}
void func_3(int* param_3) {
    *param_3 = 200 / (ADD(2,8) * MUL(10,2));
}
void func_4() {
    global_var = 100 / ADD(2,3);
    header_var = 10;
}
```

**q1_header.h**:

```
#ifndef Q1_HEADER_H
#define Q1_HEADER_H
#define ADD(x,y) x + y
#define MUL(x,y) x * y
#define loop(x,n) for(int x=1; x<=n; ++x)
static int header_var = -1;
#endif
```

Comment: There are *two* `header_var` static variables in your program; one static to `q1_helper.cpp` and one static to `q1_main.cpp` Remember, the preprocessor `#include` is little more than "include this file content as if it were all within this file". Therefore, imagine `q1_main.cpp` now has `static int header_var = -1;` and so does `q1_helper.cpp`. You receive no warnings/errors because there are none. You told the compiler to do something well-within the realm of reason (take it or leave it), and it did just what you asked.

Comment: @WhozCraig Wow, I couldn't notice that! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @WhozCraig That makes sense but how **q1_main.cpp** and **q1_helper.cpp** both can access the **q1_header.h** ? Because there is an ```#ifndef``` statement at the beginning of that file. Isn't that mean we can access this header file only one time but you said that `**q1_helper.cpp** and **q1_main.cpp** have separate ```static int header_var = -1;```. How is it possible? I'm so confused. Thank you for your time already.

Comment: You included the header in *each* cpp file. The `#ifdef` you refer to is active for *each* cpp  file not universally across all of them. Get your book and read how the preprocessor works.